# Html into wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I need to make a fixed bottom footer to my WordPress web, with some buttons including js with a popover. I've Pillar Theme and I only need to make this change. I need to put it into my footer.php. But when I try, nothing works. I do not know if this is the best way to do that. Here is the code that I do for the footer:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

   <!-- Styles just for demo -->
  <style>
   @font-face {
  font-family: 'social-icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;

  src: url('font/social.eot?44259375');
  src: url('font/social.eot?44259375#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('font/social.woff?44259375') format('woff'), url('font/social.ttf?44259375') format('truetype'), url('font/social.svg?44259375#social') format('svg');
}
/* Share button
***********************************************/
.need-share-button {
  position: relative;

  display: inline-block;
}
.need-share-button_dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;

  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;

  width: 240px;

  -webkit-transition: .3s;
          transition: .3s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(.1);
      -ms-transform: scale(.1);
          transform: scale(.1);
  text-align: center;

  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;
}
.need-share-button-opened .need-share-button_dropdown {
  visibility: visible;

  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);

  opacity: 1;
}

.need-share-button_link {
  display: inline-block;

  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;

  line-height: 40px;

  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
.need-share-button_link:after {
  font: normal normal normal 16px/1 'social-icons';

  text-align: center;
  text-transform: none;

  speak: none;
}
.need-share-button_link:hover {
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
          transition: .3s;

  opacity: .7;
}
/* Dropdown position
***********************************************/

.need-share-button_dropdown-top-center {
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;

  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* Default theme
***********************************************/
.need-share-button-default .need-share-button_button {
  display: inline-block;

  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;

  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;

  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;

  background-image: url("share.png") no-repeat;

}

.need-share-button-default .need-share-button_button span {
  background-image: url("share.png") no-repeat;
}

.need-share-button-default .need-share-button_button:hover {
  color: #737373;
}

/* Network buttons
***********************************************/
.need-share-button_mailto {
  color: #efbe00;
}
.need-share-button_mailto:after {
  content: '\e80a';
}
.need-share-button_mailto.need-share-button_link-box {
  color: #fff;

  background: #efbe00;
}
.need-share-button_twitter {
  color: #00acec;
}
.need-share-button_twitter:after {
  content: '\e813';
}
.need-share-button_twitter.need-share-button_link-box {
  color: #fff;

  background: #00acec;
}
.need-share-button_facebook {
  color: #3b5998;
}
.need-share-button_facebook:after {
  content: '\e80e';
}
.need-share-button_facebook.need-share-button_link-box {
  color: #fff;

  background: #3b5998;
}

   .wrapper {
    text-align: center;
   }
   footer { 
          background-color: black;
          position: fixed;
          bottom: 0;
          width: 100%;
          left: 0;
          height: 60px;
        }
      footer .col-sm {
       text-align: center;
      }
      a {
       color: white;
       text-decoration: none;
      }
      footer .col-sm > span {
       padding: 7px 0 0px;
       display: inline-block;
      }
      footer .col-sm > span > a:hover {
       color: #737373;
       text-decoration: none;
      }

      #homefooter a{
       background-image: url("home.png");
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       padding-bottom: 35px;
      }

      #donarfooter a {
       background-image: url("donar.png");
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       padding-bottom: 35px;
      }

      footer a span {
       visibility: hidden;
      }

  /* ------------------------------------ MEDIA QUERIES -------------------------------------------*/

      @media (max-width: 900px){
    footer .col-sm {
     width: 25%;
    }
    footer span {
     padding: 0 !important;

    }
   }
  /* ------------------------------------ MEDIA QUERIES -------------------------------------------*/


  /* ------------------------------------ SEARCH STYLES -------------------------------------------*/

    * {
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 .openBtn {
   background: #f1f1f1;
   border: none;
   padding: 10px 15px;
   font-size: 20px;
   cursor: pointer;
 }

 .openBtn:hover {
   background: #bbb;
 }

 .overlay {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   display: none;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
 }

 .overlay-content {
   position: relative;
   top: 46%;
   width: 80%;
   text-align: center;
   margin-top: 30px;
   margin: auto;
 }

 .overlay .closebtn {
   position: absolute;
   top: 20px;
   right: 45px;
   font-size: 60px;
   cursor: pointer;
   color: white;
 }

 .overlay .closebtn:hover {
   color: #ccc;
 }

 .overlay input[type=text] {
   padding: 15px;
   font-size: 17px;
   border: none;
   float: left;
   width: 80%;
   background: white;
 }

 .overlay input[type=text]:hover {
   background: #f1f1f1;
 }

 .overlay button {
   float: left;
   width: 20%;
   padding: 15px;
   background: #ddd;
   font-size: 17px;
   border: none;
   cursor: pointer;
 }

 .overlay button:hover {
   background: #bbb;
 }
 /* ------------------------------------ SEARCH STYLES -------------------------------------------*/


</style>

 </head>
 <body>
  <section>
   <div id="myOverlay" class="overlay">
    <span class="closebtn" onclick="closeSearch()" title="Close Overlay">×</span>
      <div class="overlay-content">
        <form action="/action_page.php">
           <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
           <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </form>
     </div>
   </div>
     </section>
  <footer class="fixed-bottom">
   <div class="container-fluid" style="height: 100%">
    <div class="row" style="height: 100%">
     <div class="col-sm" id="homefooter">
      <span>
       <a href="google.com"><span>HOME</span></a> 
      </span>      
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm" style="height: 100%; border-left: solid 0.5px white; border-right: solid 0.5px white">
      <div class="wrapper">
       <img src="share.png">
       <div id="share-button-2" class="need-share-button-default" data-share-position="topCenter" data-share-icon-style="box" data-share-networks="Mailto,Twitter,Facebook"></div>
      </div>      
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm" id="donarfooter">
      <span>
       <a href="google.com"><span>CONTRIBUIR</span></a>
      </span>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm" id="donarfooter">
      <span>
       <button class="openBtn" onclick="openSearch()">BUSCAR</button>
      </span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </footer>
  <script>
   /*********************************************** 
  needShareButton 
  - Version 1.0.0
  - Copyright 2015 Dzmitry Vasileuski
 - Licensed under MIT (http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)
***********************************************/

(function() {

 // share dropdown class
 window.needShareDropdown = function(elem, options) {
  // create element reference
  var root = this;
  root.elem = elem;
  root.elem.className += root.elem.className.length ? ' need-share-button' : 'need-share-button';

  /* Helpers
  ***********************************************/

    // get title from html 
    root.getTitle = function() {
     var content;
     // check querySelector existance for old browsers
     if (document.querySelector) {
      if (content = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:title"]') || document.querySelector('meta[name="twitter:title"]')) {
        return content.getAttribute('content');
      } else if (content = document.querySelector('title')) {
        return content.innerText;
      } else
       return '';
    } else {
     if (content = document.title)
        return content.innerText;
      else
       return '';
    }
   };

   // get image from html 
   root.getImage = function() {
     var content;
     // check querySelector existance for old browsers
     if (document.querySelector) {
      if (content = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:image"]') || document.querySelector('meta[name="twitter:image"]')) {
        return content.getAttribute('content');
      } else 
       return '';
    } else 
     return '';
   };

   // get description from html 
   root.getDescription = function() {
     var content;
     // check querySelector existance for old browsers
     if (document.querySelector) {
      if (content = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:description"]') || document.querySelector('meta[name="twitter:description"]') || document.querySelector('meta[name="description"]')) {
        return content.getAttribute('content');
      } else
        return '';
    } else {
     if (content = document.getElementsByTagName('meta').namedItem('description'))
      return content.getAttribute('content');
     else
      return '';
    }
   };

   // share urls for all networks
   root.share = {
    'mailto' : function() {
     var url = 'mailto:?subject=' + encodeURIComponent(root.options.title) + '&body=Thought you might enjoy reading this: ' + encodeURIComponent(root.options.url) + ' - ' + encodeURIComponent(root.options.description);

     window.location.href = url;
    },
    'twitter' : function() {
     var url = root.options.protocol + 'twitter.com/home?status=';
     url += encodeURIComponent(root.options.title) + encodeURIComponent(root.options.url);

        root.popup(url);
    },
    'facebook' : function() {
     var url = root.options.protocol + 'www.facebook.com/sharer/share.php?';
     url += 'u=' + encodeURIComponent(root.options.url);
     url += '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(root.options.title);

        root.popup(url);
    },

   }

   // open share link in a popup
   root.popup = function(url) {
    // set left and top position
    var popupWidth = 500,
      popupHeight = 400,
      // fix dual screen mode
      dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left,
       dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top,
       width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width,
       height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height,
       // calculate top and left position
       left = ((width / 2) - (popupWidth / 2)) + dualScreenLeft,
       top = ((height / 2) - (popupHeight / 2)) + dualScreenTop,

   // show popup
   shareWindow = window.open(url,'targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=' + popupWidth + ', height=' + popupHeight + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);

    // Puts focus on the newWindow
     if (window.focus) {
         shareWindow.focus();
     }
   }

   /* Set options
  ***********************************************/

  // create default options
  root.options = {
   shareButtonClass: false, // child selector of custom share button
   iconStyle: 'default', // default or box
   boxForm: 'horizontal', // horizontal or vertical
   position: 'bottomCenter', // top / middle / bottom + Left / Center / Right
   buttonText: 'COMPARTIR',
   protocol: ['http', 'https'].indexOf(window.location.href.split(':')[0]) === -1 ? 'https://' : '//',
   url: window.location.href,
   title: root.getTitle(),
   image: root.getImage(),
   description: root.getDescription(),
   networks: 'Mailto,Twitter,Facebook'
  }

    // integrate data attribute options
    for (var option in root.elem.dataset) {
     // replace only 'share-' prefixed data-attributes
      if (option.match(/share/)) {
        var new_option = option.replace(/share/, '');
        if (!new_option.length) {
            continue;
        }
        new_option = new_option.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + new_option.slice(1);
        root.options[new_option] = root.elem.dataset[option];
      }
    }

    // convert networks string into array
    root.options.networks = root.options.networks.toLowerCase().split(',');

  /* Create layout
  ***********************************************/

  // create dropdown button if not exists
  if (root.options.shareButtonClass) {
   for (var i = 0; i < root.elem.children.length; i++) {
    if (root.elem.children[i].className.match(root.options.shareButtonClass))
     root.button = root.elem.children[i];
   }
  }
  if (!root.button) {
   root.button = document.createElement('span');
   root.button.innerText = root.options.buttonText;
   root.elem.appendChild(root.button);
  }
  root.button.className += ' need-share-button_button';

  // show and hide dropdown
    root.button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     if (!root.elem.className.match(/need-share-button-opened/)) {
      root.elem.className += ' need-share-button-opened';
     } else {
      root.elem.className = root.elem.className.replace(/\s*need-share-button-opened/g,'');
     }
    });

  // create dropdown
  root.dropdown = document.createElement('span');
  root.dropdown.className = 'need-share-button_dropdown';
  root.elem.appendChild(root.dropdown);

 
  // set dropdown position
  setTimeout(function() {
   switch (root.options.position) {
      case 'topCenter':
        root.dropdown.className += ' need-share-button_dropdown-top-center';
        root.dropdown.style.marginLeft = - root.dropdown.offsetWidth / 2 + 'px';
        break
      }
  },1);


  // fill fropdown with buttons
  var iconClass = root.options.iconStyle == 'default' ? 'need-share-button_link need-share-button_' : 'need-share-button_link-' + root.options.iconStyle + ' need-share-button_link need-share-button_';
  for (var network in root.options.networks) {
   var link = document.createElement('span');
       network = root.options.networks[network];
   link.className = iconClass + network;
   link.dataset.network = network;
   root.dropdown.appendChild(link);

   // add share function to event listener
      link.addEventListener('click', function() {
       root.share[this.dataset.network]();
      });
    }

  }

})();

  </script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>  
   new needShareDropdown(document.getElementById('share-button-2'));
  </script>
  <script>
function openSearch() {
  document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.display = "block";
}

function closeSearch() {
  document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
  
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide minimal example, not full code of page

Answer (score 0):

You can try Sticky footer with `jQuery`. Add this code in your `js` file.

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    /* sticky footer function */
    StickyFooter()
});

/* Script on resize */
jQuery(window).resize(function($) {

    /* sticky footer function */
    StickyFooter();

});

/* Script on load
----------------------------------*/
jQuery(window).load(function($) {

    /* sticky footer function */
    StickyFooter();

}); 

/* Sticky Footer Function */
function StickyFooter(){
    var Stickyfooter = jQuery( 'footer' ).outerHeight()
    jQuery('#wrapper').css('margin-bottom',-Stickyfooter) /* Here #wrapper is your main <div> of <body> */
    jQuery('#wrapper').css('padding-bottom',Stickyfooter)
}
```